# Photoshop How to save selection to PNG

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, png

I have a largish PSD file with a couple of hundred layers, that I would like to extract selected areas from into PNG files.

Areas can consist of a couple of layers.

Being new to Photoshop, I have been using the following workaround. Duplicate needed layers into a new scratch PSD file of same size, TRIM to transparency, Save As PNG, undo TRIM, hide layers, rinse and repeat...

I suppose I could do it without the scratch file and just crop selection, Save As PNG and undo, but there must be a nicer method.

What other ways are there to accomplish this export of a selected area to PNG?

EDIT: This is on Windows Xp running Photoshop CS3 Extended

Answer (score 54, accepted):

- Make your selection
- Edit -> Copy Merged
- File -> New (Photoshop should automatically suggest a new canvas size to match the selection size)
- Edit -> Paste
- File -> Save As (PNG)
- Rinse and repeat... (keyboard shortcuts are handy here)

(Tested on Photoshop CS4)

Comment: Photoshop engineers should seriously think about improving this because it's tedious to do something so simple with 6 steps, it  should have, at most, 2 steps, select and export. simple isn't it ?

Comment: I beta test for Adobe for almost 10 years. I have asked for a new interface every single year. Photoshop UI is obtrusive, annoying, vintage from the nineties. At one time someone there asked me to stop asking for this stuff, because I was filling too many feature requests and creating "noise" on their system. How can I company bash a beta tester for suggesting improvements is beyond me.

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts for these steps: 1. `ctrl + shift +c`, 2. `ctrl + n`, 3. `ctrl + v`, 4. `ctrl + s`. 5. `ctrl + w`

Answer (score 19):

Try selecting the areas with the Slice tool and then File > Export for web & devices.

Comment: I have been using this method more and more as compared to the original answer. Presumably, this is what Photoshop developers intended to be used for this particular problem.

Comment: +1 better than the accepted answer, especially if you need to repeat this procedure a lot.

Comment: this doesn't work for any selections that aren't rectangular and parallel to the edges of the image, whereas the above method works for all shapes and sizes

Comment: @think123 True. Yet the resulting PNG is still rectangular. You could use a mask to make the shapes you want to have in the resulting Slice export.

Comment: @TomasAndrle I am trying to extract scanned pictures - I have scanned four or so images together onto one large scan file, except these pictures were not positioned exactly straight, so it's difficult for me to slice them effectively.

Answer (score 3):

I tackled this by creating a script that I put in `Presets\Scripts\Export Selection to PNG.jsx`

The code as follows:

```
app.displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO;

var pngSaveOptions = new PNGSaveOptions();
pngSaveOptions.compression = 9;

var hasSelection;
var docRef;
try {
    hasSelection = !!app.activeDocument.selection.bounds;
} catch (err) {
    hasSelection = false;
}

if (hasSelection) {
    app.activeDocument.selection.copy(true);
    var w = app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[2];
    var h = app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[3];
    docRef = app.documents.add(w, h);
    docRef.paste();
} else {
    docRef = app.activeDocument;
}
var file = File.saveDialog("Export as PNG to...");
if (file && ((file.exists && confirm("Overwrite " + file +"?")) || !file.exists)) {
    docRef.saveAs(file, pngSaveOptions, !hasSelection, Extension.LOWERCASE);
    if (hasSelection) {
    docRef.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
    }
}
```

The script above will handle no-selection as a "select all" and checks if the target file exists confirming an overwrite.

This script is triggered from the `File->Scripts->Export Selection to PNG`

Comment: I improved Archimedes' answer by making the new document call open on a transparent background, and by trimming before the save. You can find the updated script here: https://pastebin.com/tmk2h8yp

Comment: app.activeDocument.selection.bounds contains [xMin, yMin, xMax, yMax], so

var w = app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[2] - app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[0];
var h = app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[3] - app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[1];

Answer (score -1):

Make a selection. Then hit Ctr or CMD  + J to copy that selection into a new layer. then:

```
File -> Scripts -> Export Layer to Files...
```

[image: Export Layers to files]

If your layer is smaller than the full width/height of the canvas don't forget to check `Trim Layers`.

Comment: The question is not about exporting layers to files. It is about saving a selection as a file. The question specifically states "Areas can consist of a couple of layers."